# What is the significance of Macron's proposed status change to the European Flag, and what steps would be needed to make this a reality?

Tags: europe, france, symbols, flag

President Macron said he wants to officially recognize the status of flag of Europe (my translation).

Does this mean that the flag has been decorative only up until now?  What would officially recognizing it mean for France (based on other Europeean countries that have officially recognized it)?

Are there other countries where the head of state is proposing to recognize the European Flag?

Answer (score 8):

Macron is [responding/reacting to Mélenchon](http://www.lemonde.fr/politique/article/2017/10/10/macron-veut-reconnaitre-le-statut-du-drapeau-europeen_5199031_823448.html)'s (FR) fight to get rid of the EU flag in parliament.

Until now the flag basically was symbolic but not much more. With this move, France will join the 16 other nations (the cited source unfortunately doesn't say which ones) that officially recognize the EU flag and its anthem.

Comment: Wikipedia lists the states that recognize the EU flag as an official symbol(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Europe#Recognition_by_member_states), citing an EU report on the Treaty of Lisbon as a source (https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:C:2007:306:0231:0271:EN:PDF). See section C, par 52 on page 37)